# Refused connections with urls containing www

Tags: firewall, windows-firewall

Recently, on my development machine, something has changed such that when I attempt to access my website with www in the name, the connection is refused.

eg. [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) refuses connection and https://www.example.com refuses connection

Notes:

- all other machines that I've tested can access my page via these urls

I have a feeling that this might be a firewall issue. I recently installed a vpn. It is not actively running on my machine when I have this issue, however.

Any thoughts as to what settings I should be looking at on windows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I had defined [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) in my hosts file.

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts